# Database settings cached?

Tags: database, cache

Working on my first EE site (but have worked with several other CMSs) and I'm having issues with the database connection. I've pulled down files from a live site to set up a development version following the steps on the [Moving ExpressionEngine to Another Server page](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html). I've tried using the dbtest.php and can connect to the local database with no issues but when I use the same settings in the database.php file, I get a connection error. Did a little digging and the settings seem to be cached. If I do a var_dump on $this in the DB_driver.php file under if ( ! $this->conn_id) the live settings are appearing in a ar_cache_set array. I did clear the caches before downloading the live database. With a die(mysql_error()) right below that line it gives me a "not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" error. Any ideas on how to clear this? I'm not really sure where it's coming from. cache_on is set to FALSE in the database settings.

Comment: I have figured this out but have to wait 6 hours before I can answer it... config directory was set up as a symbolic link on the live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured this out - nothing to do with caching. The main config directory on the live site was set up as a symbolic link with the actual config directory in the web root. That completely threw me off because it looked like there were 2 config directories in my FTP program. I was changing the one in the root and had actually downloaded and uploaded the directories in both spots instead of recreating the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you are having an issue. I cant think of an answer other than step 7 verify permissions.

However, once you solve it,  Id  recommend using [master config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) to set up your environments. It does makes things much easier!